# What are pins and how do I draw them?

Tags: crayon-physics-deluxe

In Crayon Physics Deluxe, I can't draw more than one object or click the ball to get my solution to count as "elegant", but I can draw pins.

What are pins and how do I create them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pins are small circles that act as pivots or rotational points. To draw one, simply draw a very small circle. If you do it right, it will turn into a small, animated circle. You can then draw other objects (like hammers) which will rotate via gravity.

Attaching an object to two pins makes it completely unmovable, or as far I have seen.

Comment: Oh this look just like my answer... :P

Comment: @Warface Well, you did kind of give the general idea of a 'pin', just I added somewhat more detail :p

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work for me, every small circle I draw just falls down. Help?

Answer (score 4):

Pins are a small draw circle that when you put a form attached to it, it will rotate around the pin.